# Redirecting another domain without showing first domain's url in address bar

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I want to redirect users immediately, when they click my link (ex. abc.com/redirect) to another domain ex(xyz.com).

But I don't want to show users anything about first url(abc.com/redirect)

I use

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=xyz.com">
```

but it shows first abc.com/redirect for just a moment and redirect after it. Is there a way not showing abc.com ?

---

I use javascript/php/html/.htaccess but all of them shows first url(abc.com/redirect) . I develop an chrome extension that redirect a url(ex. xyz.com) but i have to change my redirection url sometimes (like xyz2.com),

so i redirect my extension click event to abc.com/redirect and this url sends user to xyz.com. But I dont want to show user abc.com/redirect

---

I change my algorithm. First I get the URL from abc.com/redirect.html with GET method with JavaScript and then i open new tab with xyz.com URL. So users cannot see abc.com/redirect.html. Thanks for all answers I solved my problem.

Comment: Use a htaccess Redirect instead

Comment: I use javascript/php/html/.htaccess but all of them shows first url(abc.com/redirect)

I develop an chrome extension that redirect a url(ex. xyz.com) but i have to change my redirection url sometimes (like xyz2.com),

so i redirect my extension click event to abc.com/redirect and this url sends user to xyz.com. But I dont want to show user abc.com/redirect

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `header()` function provides a feature called `Location:`. This will redirect you to any URL without initially showing your URL. Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) as well.

```
header('Location: http://example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I also try php header but it shows abc.com/redirect.php

Comment: Note: if you use this approach, for SEO to work, you should include the 301 permanent redirect code: header("Location: http://example.com",true,301);

Answer (score 0):

With htaccess you can do something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/redirect/?$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ http://destination.com/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

This will redirect `http://example.com/redirect` but not `http://example.com`.

I had to use example.com and destination.com due to restrictions on SO :/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also try .htaccess redirect but it shows mydomain.com/redirect for a tiny moment.

I develop an chrome extension that redirect a url(ex. xyz.com) but i have to change my redirection url sometimes (like xyz2.com),

so i redirect my extension click event to abc.com/redirect and this url sends user to xyz.com. But I dont want to show user abc.com/redirect

Answer (score 0):

Or for even faster redirect, use the apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName DomainA
  Redirect permanent / http://DomainB/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a standard redirect will always show the link for a tiny amount. One way to redirect without an intermediate URL could be to be have the link a submit button of a form that posts to a PHP file with a header(Location: __).

```
<form action="redirect.php" method="post">
  <button type="submit">Link</button>
</form>
```

Then redirect.php could just look like..

```
<?php header('Location: example.com'); ?>
```

This would redirect without any intermediate URL showing. If using a button was not possible, you could look in to jQuery.post which you could hook to an anchor  tag.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/